# macro takes out subject details

Tags: excel, for-loop, outlook, vba

I have written this macro. I would like to take out the subject details for each email and display it in a worksheet. The code currently loops through all emails and their subjects, but i am experiencing issues when trying to display in a csv or worksheet. In this code i have commented out the displaying to a worksheet. with both ways I am experiencing issues.

```
Sub subdetails()
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application

Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.Folders("UA Forms")            '   GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Inbox = Inbox.Folders("Inbox")

    i = 0
    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox", vbInformation, _
        "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub

    End If
'''Section experiecing the problem'''
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    'Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    'Dim logSTR As String
    iCol = 1
    iRow = 3
   ' My_filenumber = FreeFile

    'logSTR = Item

    'Open "\\Dfs52672.link2\My Documents\ExcelTutorials\authors.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
        'Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
    'Close #My_filenumber

    'i = i + 1
    'MsgBox "Your record has been logged"
    'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Item
    Columns(6).Value = Item
    i = i + 1
    MsgBox "I Found" & i & "attached files."
    Next Item

GetAttachments_exit:

        Set Atmt = Nothing
        Set Item = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub

GetAttachment_err:

    MsgBox "An error has occurred." _
    & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
    & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
    , vbCritical, "Error!"

    Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: I shall try it at work as I dont have access to it at the moment

Answer (score 0):

To list in Excel (Col A) the subject line of emails in your inbox try changing your loop to this:

```
iRow = 3

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Item.Subject

    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Item
```

---

This is assuming you have an open workbook and references have been made.  If not you should add the following:

```
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

Dim wksNew As Worksheet
Set wksNew = wbNew.Worksheets("Sheet1")

iRow = 3

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    wksNew.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Item.Subject

    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Item
```